# How to make a TreeView with fixed column like Blend's

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

I am trying to implement something like this. The problem is how to have scrollbar at bottom and fixed collumn at the right ? I am using WPF 4.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585650/wpf-keep-the-most-left-column-of-a-treeview-visible-while-scrolling-horizontally

Comment: Perhaps useful:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_treelistview_control.aspx